# How to limit upload file size in express.js

Tags: node.js, upload, express

i got this error says

```
error:request entity too large
```

when uploading a video about 30MB,

here is the setting code

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
    uploadDir:'./Temp',
    maxFieldsSize:'2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ',
}));
```

am not sure how to set the maxFieldsSize property, need some help!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Express uses connect middleware, you can specify the file upload size by using the following

```
app.use(express.limit('4M'));
```

[Connect Limit middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/limit.html)

Comment: also make sure you put this above bodyParser(), happy coding!

Comment: but dosen't express use node-formidable? and the express doc says "The bodyParser() middleware utilizes the node-formidable module internally, and accepts the same options."

Comment: I don't know about older versions, but as of v3.01 (current) uploads look as if they are handled directly through connect

Comment: limit('4mb') seems to be the correct syntax (nowadays at least).

Comment: note: this answer is no longer valid, and only applicable to a version of Express that is no longer available.

Comment: stackoverflow admin pls remove this answer

Answer (score 11):

In 2020 Express uses the body-parser urlencoded function to control the limit. 
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded

These are the default settings inside node_modules>body-parser>lib>types>urlencoded.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
  var extended = opts.extended !== false
  var inflate = opts.inflate !== false
  var limit = typeof opts.limit !== 'number'
    ? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb')
    : opts.limit
  var type = opts.type || 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  var verify = opts.verify || false
```

You can see here that the default setting for limit is 100kb.
so in order to up that you can use

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '2gb' }));
```

here are the filetype options available via NPM package bytes ( used by bodyparser )
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytes

```
"b" for bytes
"kb" for kilobytes
"mb" for megabytes
"gb" for gigabytes
"tb" for terabytes
"pb" for petabytes
```

I'm sure this was overkill but I hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 9):

```
// Comment sart   
// app.use(express.bodyParser({
//    uploadDir:'./Temp',
//    maxFieldsSize:'2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ',
// }));  

// Add this code for maximun 150mb 
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '150mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
limit: '150mb',
extended: true
})); 

// I did it Okay. Goood luck
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.use(express.limit('4mb'));
```

But you must make sure you add this line above the below,

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

or

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

depending on which version you are using.

Comment: answer is no longer valid in 2016 now that nodejs took out limit middleware

Comment: ^^ what he says

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Express 4. I tried numerous app.use() statements, including the non-deprecated ones listed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large), but none of them worked.

Instead, it turned out I only needed to add one line to index.js to change the maxFileSize option in the Formidable module:

```
// create an incoming form object
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

// ADD THIS LINE to increase file size limit to 10 GB; default is 200 MB
form.maxFileSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Source: Comments from [here](http://shiya.io/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var upload = multer({ storage : storage2, limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50 } });
```

correct format for increasing file uploading size with multer in nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue, did what the responses here said. didnt seem to work out, ting is for me my node js was on cloud im using nginx so it. so basically i just have to add this to my ningix and it worked: `server:

server {
...
client_max_body_size 100M;
}`