# Error: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm receiving the following error with express:

```
Error: request entity too large
    at module.exports (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:16:15)
    at json (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:60:5)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:53:5)
    at next (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5)
    at next (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.logger (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:158:5)
    at next (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle] (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:55:61)
    at next (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
TypeError: /Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/app/views/includes/foot.jade:31
    29| script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/socketio/connect.js")
    30| 
  > 31| if (req.host='localhost')
    32|     //Livereload script rendered 
    33|     script(type='text/javascript', src='http://localhost:35729/livereload.js')  
    34| 

Cannot set property 'host' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:152:8), <anonymous>:273:15)
    at /Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:153:35
    at Object.exports.render (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:197:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:233:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:218:21)
    at View.render (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:801:7)
    at Object.handle (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/config/express.js:82:29)
    at next (/Users/michaeljames/Documents/Projects/Proj/mean/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:188:17)

POST /api/0.1/people 500 618ms
```

I am using meanstack. I have the following use statements in my express.js

```
//Set Request Size Limit
app.use(express.limit(100000000));
```

Within fiddler I can see the content-length header with a value of: 1078702

I believe this is in octets, this is 1.0787 megabytes.

I have no idea why express is not letting me post the json array I was posting previously in another express project that was not using the mean stack project structure.

Comment: quick note on this to anyone coming to this question - make sure your issue is actually the node server or body parser. For example I'm using body parser correctly but I got this error because I for to set the max body size in the NGINX conf file.

Answer (score 1561, accepted):

I had the same error recently, and all the solutions I tried did not work.

After some digging, I found that setting `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));` **did** set the limit correctly.

When adding a `console.log('Limit file size: ' + limit);` in `node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:46` and restarting node, I get this output in the console:

```
Limit file size: 1048576
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Limit file size: 52428800
Express server listening on port 3002
```

We can see that at first, when loading the `connect` module, the limit is set to 1mb (1048576 bytes). Then when I set the limit, the `console.log` is called again and this time the limit is 52428800 (50mb). However, I still get a `413 Request entity too large`.

Then I added `console.log('Limit file size: '+limit);` in  `node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:10` and saw another line in the console when calling the route with a big request (before the error output) :

```
Limit file size: 1048576
```

This means that somehow, somewhere, `connect` resets the limit parameter and ignores what I specified. I tried specifying the `bodyParser` parameters in the route definition individually, but no luck either.

While I did not find any proper way to set it permanently, you can "*patch*" it in the module directly. If you are using Express 3.4.4, add this at line 46 of `node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js` :

```js
limit = 52428800; // for 50mb, this corresponds to the size in bytes
```

The line number might differ if you don't run the same version of Express.
Please note that this is **bad practice** and it will be **overwritten** if you update your module.

So this temporary solution works for now, but as soon as a solution is found (or the module fixed, in case it's a module problem) you should update your code accordingly.

I have opened [an issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1815) about this problem.

**[edit - found the solution]**

After some research and testing, I found that when debugging, I added `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));`, but **after** `app.use(express.json());`. Express would then set the global limit to 1mb because the first parser he encountered when running the script was `express.json()`. Moving `bodyParser` above it did the trick.

That said, the `bodyParser()` method will be deprecated in Connect 3.0 and should not be used. Instead, you should declare your parsers explicitly, like so :

```js
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
```

In case you need multipart (for file uploads) see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/express-js/iP2VyhkypHo/5AXQiYN3RPcJ).

**[second edit]**

Note that in Express 4, instead of `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`, you must require the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module and use its `json()` and `urlencoded()` methods, like so:

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

If the `extended` option is not explicitly defined for `bodyParser.urlencoded()`, it will throw a warning (`body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option`). This is because this option will be required in the next version and will **not** be optional anymore. For more info on the `extended` option, you can refer to the [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended) of `body-parser`.

**[third edit]**

It seems that in Express v4.16.0 onwards, we can go back to the initial way of doing this (thanks to @GBMan for the tip):

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Yes your correct, this works for me also. I have placed a message on the express issue: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1793. Which is relevant to the changes being made by express. Hopefully they will make the change soon... Thanks for you help. This has been driving me mad!

Comment: Update - Whilst the above works, according to a comment on github. Setting bodyParser within app.use with no parameters sets the global limit to 1mb. update your global statement to express.bodyParser({limit:'100mb'}). Ensure you set the limit once. you can make a lower limit per route but cannot be larger than the global limit. I do wonder what the plan is for {limit:''} within connect as i'm being told in the console its being removed in connect 3.0?

Comment: My problem was that I had express.json() parser above my bodyParser... After understanding how it all works I removed bodyParser and set de limit in the other, like `app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb'}));`. I edited my answer to reflect this!

Comment: Cool. From what I gather the next version of express once connect is 3.0. the bodyParser will still exist but not call any related code to multipart form data types.

Comment: for express 4, the indicated code throws "body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option" on the `urlencoded` call

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for pointing that out. I actually only tested `bodyParser.json()` and (falsely) assumed it would work for `urlencoded`. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: March 2015 here: For the debugging tip in this answer, the limiting is now checked (for me) at two locations in `node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js`.

Comment: Does this apply only for bodies or for the entire request or the url?

Comment: In case it helps anyone: I use a template which had "express.coffee" which set bodyParser after everything was up and running. Changing it there solved the issue. You should look for `rouge files setting bodyParser`.

Comment: Thanks for thorough explanation. After fixing one bug today, this error starts being emitted. Utilized proposed solution for Express 3.x and it works like a charm!

Comment: This is as comprehensive as this answer gets, so there is one more point for future reference that I ran into if you are using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of your node.js/express instance, which is recommended practice as well.

Nginx will throw the same `413::Request Entity is too large` exception. It wont forward the request to your express app. So we need to set `client_max_body_size 50M;` in the nginx config OR a specific server config OR even a specific location tag will work.

Comment: Thank you samuel for this ! Saved me from a world of headache, 
Cheers and +1 for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Hi
I am also facing the same issue, with Oracle MCS. But i am not using expressJs. Could anyone help me also?

Comment: Thank you, all.  Even though this post is now 3½ years old, it solved the 100KB cap of my file uploader.

Please note that since I am using Express 4, the 'express.' prefix is no longer required, at least with my project architecture.  I am using:  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '30mb'}));

Comment: I get a `body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option webapp.js:208:30`

Comment: @SamuelBolduc Express 4 no longer requires `body-parser` in order to parse `json` and `urlencoded` data.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json

Comment: I tried using this, But no working for me. express version 4.17 @SamuelBolduc

Comment: Since Express 4.16 we canu use:
`app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));`
See: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded

Comment: Just to add to the list... If you are using Firebase functions, the MAX limit is 10MB. You will actually see the limit getting overridden to 10MB.

Comment: Thankyou, your solution helped me dubug my problem with vue storefront (vsf). Turns out only i had to update the config settings in local.json from 100kb to 10mb.

Comment: i got 504 error code. on [second edit]

Comment: I have the same issue but its related to video file. when I try to upload a file under 2GB it uploads successfully but when I try to upload a video file size over 2GB, it gives me request entity too large error.
I have checked my Nginx config file and I can see it has client max body size set to 5g but still I don't know why I am having this issue.

Answer (score 185):

In my case it was not enough to add these lines :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

I tried adding the parameterLimit option on urlencoded function as the documentation says and error no longer appears.

> The parameterLimit option controls the maximum number of parameters
> that are allowed in the URL-encoded data. If a request contains more
> parameters than this value, a 413 will be returned to the client.
> Defaults to 1000.

Try with this code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

Comment: The parameterLimit was another gotcha I was missing, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Adding the "parameterLimit:50000" solves the problem.

Comment: I was struggling so hard on this until I found this answer. THANK YOU! #Relieve

Comment: I don't understand why `parameterLimit` would need to be changed (and it doesn't help in my case anyway). I'm not sending any parameters, much less 1000 (assuming it's URL parameters)

Answer (score 76):

If someone tried all the answers, but hadn't had any success yet and uses NGINX to host the site add this line to /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
client_max_body_size 100M; #100mb
```

Comment: This was my problem, thanks! One clue is that nginx's default is 1MB, so if you seem to be limited to that amount then it's probably nginx. Also, another clue: `body-parser` [will return](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#request-entity-too-large) a `limit`property and a `length` property in the error object (along with `status:413`). Nginx doesn't do this. So if you can't see those properties in the error object, it's probably a nginx limit. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717238/993683) how to change this nginx setting (config files most likely in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`)

Comment: thank you so much for this answer i believe this answer should be upvoted because it is important , personally i forgot about nginx configuration ... again big thank you

Comment: How to set limit only in express?

Comment: @аlexdykyі Answer from Vivek22 : app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));

Comment: Use the http, server, or location block to edit **client_max_body_size**.

Comment: Thank u, this was my case

Answer (score 45):

I don't think this is the express global size limit, but specifically the [connect.json middleware limit](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/7edb875a9f305e38f4d960fa46ac674038241892/lib/middleware/json.js#L27). This is 1MB by default when you use `express.bodyParser()` and don't provide a `limit` option.

Try:

```
app.post('/api/0.1/people', express.bodyParser({limit: '5mb'}), yourHandler);
```

Comment: Hi - I am using the following: app.get('/api/0.1/people/', express.bodyParser({limit:'100mb'}), tracks.all); I am still receiving the same error...

Comment: the default limit is 100kbyte as it seems now  https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit

Comment: With express in version 4.18.x in year 2023 there is no longer express.bodyParser available. How does the fix look nowadays?

Comment: @ShadowGames the top answer has a section detailing updates for express 4 using the body-parser npm package which is now a standalone separate package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965089/266795

Answer (score 38):

For express ~4.16.0, express.json with limit works directly

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you Stenal P Jolly!

Comment: express.raw should be used when posting media files.        express.raw({
    type: ["application/octet-stream", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "image/*", "video/*"],
    limit: 25 * 1024 * 1024
  })

Comment: confirmed this works for 4.17.0 as well. additionally, fwiw, your express app and it's node_module dependencies will use the configuration set here. In my case, I was not directly using express.json() in my server file when the issue occurred, but some dependencies were using it. Adding the code above as a new line resolved the issues coming from my dependencies.

Answer (score 23):

in my case .. setting `parameterLimit:50000` fixed the problem

```
app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}) );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit:50000
}));
```

Comment: This worked for me. "Request entity too large" seems to refer to large strings (like JSON) too. I was posting ~20Kib JSON and had this problem (notice that default `body-parser` payload **size** limit is OK for me). Was solved with `parameterLimit` only (no need to set any `limit`s).

Answer (score 17):

The following worked for me... Just use

```
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
```

that's it.

Tried all above and none worked. Found that even though we use like the following,

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
```

only the 1st `app.use(bodyParser());` one gets defined and the latter two lines were ignored.

Refer: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/176 >> see 'dougwilson commented on Jun 17, 2016'

Comment: THANK YOU! I also had an old app.use(bodyParser.json()); in my code before and indeed, only the first one is taken!

Answer (score 16):

2016, none of the above worked for me until i explicity set the 'type' in addition to the 'limit' for bodyparser, example:

```
  var app = express();
  var jsonParser       = bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024*20, type:'application/json'});
  var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true,limit:1024*1024*20,type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })

  app.use(jsonParser);
  app.use(urlencodedParser);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed to do also. And it has been set up so you can drive the config settings from your app script.

Comment: did you mean `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (rather than `application/x-www-form-urlencoding`)?

Comment: According to Express 4 documentation (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded),  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is already the default.

Answer (score 16):

The setting below has worked for me

**Express 4.16.1**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: false,
}))
```

**Nginx**

```
client_max_body_size 50m;
client_body_temp_path /data/temp;
```

Answer (score 15):

In my case the problem was on **Nginx configuration**. To solve it I have to edit the file: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add this line inside server block:

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

Restart Nginx and the problems its gone

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 13):

This issue happens in two cases:

1- request body is too large and server cannot process this large data. this will serve it

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

2- `req.cookies` is too large. When testing different next.js applications on the same browser, each time each app was starting on a different port if there were running some apps. Same app might end up starting at port 3000-3005 range. That means if your app saves cookie, that cookie will be saved for each port. Let's say you started 5 different apps at localhost:3000, and each one saved a cookie. If you make a request, all the cookies will be attached to the request object, in this case you will not able to process even small size of `post.body`. Solution is you have to delete all the cookies

[image]

Answer (score 11):

## A slightly different approach - the payload is *too BIG*

All the helpful answers so far deal with increasing the payload limit. But it might also be the case that the payload is indeed too big but for no good reason. If there's no valid reason for it to be, consider looking into why it's so bloated in the first place.

### Our own experience

For example, in our case, an Angular app was greedily sending an entire object in the payload. When one bloated and redundant property was removed, *the payload size was reduced by a factor of a 100*. This significantly improved performance and resolved the 413 error.

Comment: a very underrated answer. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Just adding this one line must solve it actually

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Also recommend you guys to send the whole image to the backend then convert it rather then sending the data from the frontend

Comment: can you clarify that comment? what's the difference between sending from the front and sending to the back?

Comment: @Joe I apologise i wrote this from the react point of view I meant the users to get the image in the same format then send it over to the backend using the post request then converting it there rather then getting the image and converting it into base 64 string

Answer (score 9):

After דo many tries I got my solution

I have commented this line

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and I put

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
```

Then it works

Answer (score 7):

Pass the below configs to your server to increase your request size.

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: false, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

Answer (score 6):

Little old post but I had the same problem

Using express 4.+
my code looks like this and it works great after two days of extensive testing.

```
var url         = require('url'),
    homePath    = __dirname + '/../',
    apiV1       = require(homePath + 'api/v1/start'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser').json({limit:'100mb'});

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render( homePath + 'public/template/index');
    });

    app.get('/api/v1/', function (req, res) {
        var query = url.parse(req.url).query;
        if ( !query ) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        apiV1( 'GET', query, function (response) {
            res.json(response);
        });
    });

    app.get('*', function (req,res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    app.post('/api/v1/', bodyParser, function (req, res) {
        if ( !req.body ) {
            res.json({
                status: 'error',
                response: 'No data to parse'
            });
        }
        apiV1( 'POST', req.body, function (response) {
            res.json(response);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case removing `Content-type` from the request headers worked.

Comment: Certainly this is an underappreciated answer. My point was also like this. I was trying to manage all of my headers for the requests in a place. So these common header setup was containing `Content-Type`. After removal, issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 6):

To add to [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40745569/10907864).

By default, NGINX has an upload limit of 1 MB per file. By limiting the file size of uploads, you can prevent some types of Denial-of-service (DOS) attacks and many other issues.

So when you try to upload a file above the 1MB limit you will run into a 4**13 error**.

By editing client_max_body_size, you can adjust the file upload size. Use the `http`, `server`, or `location` block to edit `client_max_body_size`.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/infohob.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/infohob.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**Reference**: [Limit File Upload Size in NGINX](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/)

Comment: Thank you so much. For this clarification I did the same but in the main file that is nginx.conf. Now I realize that will make the configuration for each server block. But I need that in only one server block i.e my backend. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've used another practice for this problem with multer dependancie.

Example:

```
multer = require('multer');

var uploading = multer({
  limits: {fileSize: 1000000, files:1},
});

exports.uploadpictureone = function(req, res) {
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.url, function(result) {
    res.send(result);
  });
};

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.route('/api/upload', uploading).all(uploadPolicy.isAllowed)
        .post(upload.uploadpictureone);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `express.json()` and [bodyParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) together it will give error as express sets its own limit.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

remove above code and just add below code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "200mb",  extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));
```

Answer (score 5):

After trying everything in this post, i was unsuccessful. But I found a solution that worked for me.
I was able to solve it without using the **body-parser** and only with the **express**.
It looked like this:

```
const express = require('express');    

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '25mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '25mb', extended: true}));
```

Don't forget to use **extended: true** to remove the deprecated message from the console.

Answer (score 5):

Work for me:

Config nginx max file zise
[https://patriciahillebrandt.com/nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/][1]

and

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "200mb",  extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));
```

Answer (score 4):

for me following snippet solved the problem.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I too faced that issue, I was making a silly mistake by repeating the `app.use(bodyParser.json())` like below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
```

by removing `app.use(bodyParser.json())`, solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue recently and bellow solution workes for me.

> ```
> Dependency : 
> express >> version : 4.17.1
> body-parser >> version": 1.19.0
> ```

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

For understanding :
[HTTP 431](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413)

> The HTTP 413 Payload Too Large response status code indicates that the
> request entity is larger than limits defined by server; the server
> might close the connection or return a Retry-After header field.

Answer (score 2):

The better use you can specify the limit of your file size as it is shown in the given lines:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}))
```

You can also change the default setting in node-modules body-parser then in the lib folder, there are JSON and text file. Then change limit here. Actually, this condition pass if you don't pass the limit parameter in the given line
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true})).

Answer (score 1):

**Express 4.17.1**

```
app.use( express.urlencoded( {
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb'
} ) )
```

[Demo csb](https://5c6sq.sse.codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Following code resolved my issue:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '5mb' });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the main trick is

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '20mb'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '20mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000,
  extended: true 
}));
```

bodyParse.json first
bodyParse.urlencoded second

Answer (score 0):

For those who start the NodeJS app in Azure under IIS, do not forget to modify web.config as explained here [Azure App Service IIS "maxRequestLength" setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186826/azure-app-service-iis-maxrequestlength-setting)

Answer (score 0):

I am using multer to upload files to AWS s3.
For me, after adding `client_max_body_size 100M;` into nginx file,
I get 400 error. (but the 413 error is gone, this means that it successfully went through nginx and reach your server)

Solution is below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71240419/15477963

My app.js file did not need to change, and remain like this, which works:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```