# Node.js Express. Large body for bodyParser

Tags: node.js, express

I use Express.js ver 4.2 and want to parse a large post (150K - 1M) but receives the error message "request entity too large". It seems that the limit is 100 K. I don't now how to change the limit in Express 4. In Express 3.x I just did -

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '5mb'}));
```

How can I change the limit in Express 4 ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The limit isn't in Express, but in the middleware.  What middleware are you using in Express 4?

Comment: If anyone has been pulling their hair out (like I was) because `body-parser` doesn't seem to be listening to your `limit`s, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40745569/993683 ==> could be `nginx` (or equivalent) limit

Answer (score 76):

With Express 4 you have to install the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/) module and use that instead:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ...

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb'}));
```

Comment: Hi. You got me on the right track. I have already done it but with the big mistake that I did it in two step. First only app.use(bodyParser.json()); and the agin app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'})); After your answer I double checked my code and removed the first app.use and it all worked. Stupid me and thanks a lot for you quick answer and help to find my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: So, if someone sends along a profile picture in a form POST, does that count toward the limit? Or is that handled by different middleware anyway, so it doesn't?

Comment: @Costa the `bodyParser` module does not handle `multipart/form-data` requests (which would be the case if you are talking about uploading files).

Comment: @mscdex Unless he is sending a base64 encoded image.

Comment: For those new to the router system in Express: These changes go on the main app.js page above your routes, not within the routes/.js files.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the "request entity too large " issue with Oracle MCS. But i am not using ExpressJS

Comment: what does "app" refers?

Comment: bodyParser.urlencoded is deprecated. what is it for?

Comment: doesnt work: SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\node\webchat\server\node_modules\body-parser\   lib\types\json.js:157:10)

Answer (score 11):

Mscdex's code works, but we should add another parameter to avoid warning now.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb', extended: true}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Express v4.x.x

Node.js v9.x.x

This is dependent on whether you are receiving data as JSON or via parameterized URL query.

I had the same problem sending a large JSON buffer. The file was ~ 43KB and I was incoming from my middleware to an express API.

I handled it as such:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

This corrected the issue for me, when the body was a large JSON object.