# Angular JS sending array of base64 to NodeJs server- Allow-Access-Control-Origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, base64

I am trying to send an array of base64 string from my Client Side(AngularJs) to my NodeJs Server.
I am encountering in a weird situation. whenever I send Object Like this:

```
{Price: 1000000, LookingFor: "Rent", RoomsNumber: 4, Area: 1000, PropertyType: "Any", Base64:['data:image/jpeg;base64,/9..'] }
```

I Get an error like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/estate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 413.
```

And when I remove the base64 the http request is working. Also when I send only one string of base 64 to server, the server accepts it.

in client side I am using angular $http :

```
self.PostEstate = function (estate) {
            console.log(serverLocation + 'estate');
            console.log('sending estate', estate);
            $http.post(serverLocation + 'estate', estate)
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log('successfully sent estate', data);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('postEstate', {
                        IsSucceded: true,
                        _id: data
                    })
                }).error(function (err) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('postEstate', {
                        Msg: err,
                        IsSucceded: false
                    })
                });
        }
```

And in my server I am using simple routing of my app:

```
app.post('/estate', function (req, res) {

    var estate = new Estate({
        Price: req.body.Price,
        LookingFor: req.body.LookingFor,
        RoomsNumber: req.body.RoomsNumber,
        Area: req.body.Area,
        PropertyType: req.body.PropertyType,
        Desc: req.body.Desc,
        photos: []
    });

    //Thats mongoose obj
    estate.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({
            _id: estate._id
        });
    });
});
```

I thinking that the post request is too big,can I remove the limit?
If not can you suggest another architecture that I can send base64 array to my server?
Thank you in advance.
PS Just Mention that I use node 10 with express 4.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not use `multipart/form-data` for uploading images?

Answer (score 1):

Your server tells you what's wrong:

> The response had HTTP status code 413.

which translates to [`Request Entity too large`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

As it looks like you want to upload images, why don't you simply use `multipart/form-data` to do so? Do you really have to send a base64 encoded string?

See this tutorial for example: https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

If you really need to send a string you can increase the limit in the `body-parser` middleware: [Node.js Express. Large body for bodyParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332561/node-js-express-large-body-for-bodyparser)

Comment: Well I didnt knew there was option of uploading the whole image. How I handle this in the server?

Comment: There's middlware like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty#readme or https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme for handling that.