# How to edit nginx.conf to increase file size upload

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to increase the `maximum file size` that can be uploaded.
After doing some research online, I found that you have to edit the file 'nginx.conf'.
The only way I can currently access this file is by going through Putty and typing in the command:

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This will open the file but I have 2 questions now:

1. How do I edit this file?
2. I found online that you have to add the following line of code:

`client_max_body_size 8M;`

Where would I put this line of code in `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

### Add *client_max_body_size*

Now that you are editing the file you need to add the line into the server block, like so;

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 8M;

    //other lines...
}
```

If you are hosting multiple sites add it to the http context like so;

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 8M;

    //other lines...
}
```

And also update the `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini file so that you can upload files of the same size.

### Saving in Vi

Once you are done you need to save, this can be done in vi with pressing `esc` key and typing `:wq` and returning.

### Restarting Nginx and PHP

Now you need to restart nginx and php to reload the configs. This can be done using the following commands;

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Or whatever your php service is called.

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to add it to `http {` context so that all servers inherit it. And make sure that you adjust your `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` to match your nginx setting. If you are running Laravel using Homestead/Vagrant, that file is located at `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I am using Laravel Homestead.  So I opened '/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini' and found the line of code 'upload_max_filesize = 2M', so I want to change it so that '2M' becomes '8M'.  Once I make this edit, do I just hit 'Ctrl Z' to exit out of the file and then run 'sudo service nging restart'?

Comment: You dont hit ctrl-z You need to save it with vi press esc then type :wq and press enter.

Comment: I'm trying to use the command ':wq!' after making the edit but I keep getting the message 'E212 Can't open file for writing'.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Come out of the editor, prepend the vi command with sudo. Like so; sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or sudo vi /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly!  I had to use the 'sudo' command in front of vi so that it granted it admin access and allowed for the files to be edited.  After making your changes, I ran the 'sudo service' commands listed above and now I can upload images with large file sizes.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: `sudo nginx -s reload` reloads configuration without restarting nginx

Comment: php needs `post_max_size` as well.

Comment: You can also reload nginx config using this command:

`service nginx reload`

Comment: what is 8M? does it mean 8 MB size?

Answer (score 16):

In case if one is using nginx proxy as a docker container (e.g. [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)), there is the following way to configure `client_max_body_size` (or other properties):

1. Create a custom config file e.g. `/etc/nginx/proxy.conf` with a right value for this property
2. When running a container, add it as a volume e.g. `-v /etc/nginx/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf:ro`

Personally found this way rather convenient as there's no need to build a custom container to change configs. I'm not affiliated with `jwilder/nginx-proxy`, was just using it in my project, and the way described above helped me. Hope it helps someone else, too.

Comment: This related project: https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion (the nginx-proxy from jwilder combined with certificate generation from lets encrypt) has a neat script to do this and has this option preconfigured (to 100M). Create the .env from the sample; uncomment the line ```#USE_NGINX_CONF_FILES=true```; run ```start.sh``` and finally ```docker-compose up```. (I'm not affiliated with either project).

Answer (score 13):

First Navigate the Path of **php.ini**

> sudo vi /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

then, next change

```
upload_max_filesize = 999M
post_max_size = 999M
```

then `ESC-->:wq`

Now Lastly Paste this command,

> sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service

you are done.

Comment: This question is about the nginx web server, not the PHP programming language

Comment: This is worked for me @Rafik Farhad. It might help other too. I know it is an nginx configuration question. But In some cases, it might be required to add some other functionality as well. So I did here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase client_max_body_size and upload_max_filesize + post_max_size all day long. Without adjusting HTTP timeout it will never work.

//You need to adjust this, and probably on PHP side also.
client_body_timeout    2min   // 1GB fileupload

Comment: More information about tweaking your web-server here: https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/configuration/files/big_file_upload_configuration.html