# Odoo database restore error

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

When I want to restore database from web I allways get this error: **"Database restore error"**. And I have no idea why.
I checked odoo logs, postresql logs and even nginx logs but there are no errors.
Interesting fact is this that I can make a database backup from web and everything is Ok but then I want to restore this backup I have magic error.

Also I tried to make restore from server by pg_dump everything also is OK. The problem is only restoring from web and I have no idea why..

Could anybody have the same situation?

UPDATE:
when I turn off multiprocessing everything also is ok.

Comment: Hello fueggit, I guess your database size is much bigger. You can try increasing the upload size from nginx.conf file and php.ini. Look here for more in detail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717013/how-to-edit-nginx-conf-to-increase-file-size-upload

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My database size is about 1.1 GB and client_max_body_size on nginx config file is setted to 24000M; at server block.

Comment: Are you restoring from front or by cmd ?

Comment: If I am restoring from cmd I have no problem, everything is OK. Error comes when I am restoring from front (web).

Comment: Have you tried increasing the same in php.ini file? I guess you have only increased client_max_body_size in nginx.conf file. Make sure you have increased both files to 24000M and restarting both services nginx and php. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @PranjalGami .. "php.ini"? - *Odoo is Python* .. not PHP. This has nothing to do with PHP.