# Laravel 5.1 Max image size

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and php 7.
I try to implement an image upload. Large images fails to upload. (A white screen appears with no error message) I tested it locally on xampp and on a webspace.
With small images it works.
It fails with an image of 2.5MB but the max value is 5000.

My controller:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)

{

      if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {

            $targetFolder = public_path().'/images/';

            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // add

            $picture = sha1($name . time()) . '.' . $extension; //add

            $image->move($targetFolder, $picture);

            $image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make(sprintf('images/%s', $picture))->resize(640, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $image->sharpen(10);
            $image->save();

            $form= new Image();
            $form->filename = $picture;
            $form->appartement_id = $appartement->id;
            $form->save();
        }
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been successfully');

}
```

The questions:

1. Why there is no error message? Only a white screen appears when it fails to upload. (Maybe there is a necessary configuration to do in one of the laravel config files?
2. Why it works with smaller images? Where in xampp and on the webspace it's a configuration necessary?

---

According to my phpinfo file, I have the following values defined: (Local on xampp)

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

On my webspace each is 200M.
This values should be high enough?

Answer (score 1):

Since it works with smaller files, I'm guessing this is related to your PHP configuration and not your code.  You should make sure both of these settings in php.ini are large enough (you can change the values to meet your needs).

```
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
```

You can run the phpinfo() function to confirm the current settings for your server and make sure your changes have been successful.

Comment: On my local machine they are post_max_size = 8M and upload_max_filesize = 10M. On my webspace each is 200M. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check server configuration?
**PHP** - [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)
**NGINX** - [How to edit nginx.conf to increase file size upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717013/how-to-edit-nginx-conf-to-increase-file-size-upload)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to increase values in php.ini as per your recommendation, for example:

```
upload_max_filesize = 24M 
post_max_size = 32M
```

In laravel validation `files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.`
check [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-size)

try in controller

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['your message,here']);
```

Comment: On my local machine they are post_max_size = 8M and upload_max_filesize = 10M. On my webspace each is 200M. Any other ideas?

Comment: try `return redirect()->back()` chek mu updated answer

Comment: return redirect()->back() doesn't change anything