# nginx stoutly ignore client_max_body_size

Tags: docker, nginx, dokku

Ok, I've seen all answers which as minimum mention such problem with nginx, so please. I just need to increase upload body size to 100 mb. So my setup is: simple AWS EC2 instance with 18.04 ubuntu with next `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100m;
}
```

And one of the sites `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-api.domain.ltd`:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location /media/upload {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.1.5:5000/media/upload;
        ...
        client_max_body_size 100m;
    }
```

As I assume all things done according [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) and answers like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717238/2362544). Under the hood of `http://10.0.1.5:5000` there is another one EC2 instance with `dotnet core app` started as Docker-container. All security groups, ports and other things are done: everything works, except the only one minor things which I can't fix the whole day! Even all `client_max_body_size` settings placed, the endpoint still can't handle requests with body more than 1 Mb!

Yes, I checked my dotnet app twice: it has default limit: 30 Mb for upload. So, please, try to show me the thing I missed because I'm stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed everything and finally figured out the problem. The problem was encountered in nginx which was placed in dokku on my `10.0.1.5` machine. It fixed with:

```
sudo echo 'client_max_body_size 100m;' > /home/dokku/app/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf

chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/app/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
```