# How does Heroku limit the request size?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm trying to submit a form with a file to Node+Express server. I set the bodyParser limit to 5M:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ limit: '5mb' }));
```

It works fine on local machine. However on Heroku I get "Request Entity Too Large" error for files larger than 1M.

How does Heroku put this limit and how it can be changed?

**EDIT:** The actual error is generated by the nginx and not the node app:
[image]

Comment: I don't think they have a limit, per se, but you might try more I was wondering the same with wordpress on heroku. But now php.ini and wp-config.php are both set to 1000mb for max-file size and uploads and nginx.conf 'client_max_body_size 1000m;'.  maybe there's another express property which heroku defaults unless you override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to post the resolution. The problem was only for that app. I tried to create a new app and it worked fine. So I think it was related to the specific server instance that the initial application was using. On another instance the problem didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to re-order you configuration statements, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965089/2942

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is that it works fine on local machine. It does not work only on Heroku.