# Iron-Router - Setting underlying express options

Tags: node.js, file-upload, meteor, iron-router

As mentioned in this post:
[Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large)  there seems to be a default limit in express of 1mb, and since Iron-Router is using express under the hood, I keep running into this when using Iron-Router server side routes:

```
Error: request entity too large
    at makeError (/home/cooldude/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1lv6llg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:184:15)
    at module.exports (/home/cooldude/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1lv6llg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:40:15)
    at read (/home/cooldude/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1lv6llg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:62:3)
    at [object Object].jsonParser (/home/cooldude/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.1lv6llg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:87:5)
    at packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:277:1
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at [object Object].hookWithOptions (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:276:1)
    at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
    at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1
```

I would like to be able to set these on express, perhaps after Iron-router has been loaded, but sadly there isn't much information on doing this at all:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Ideas?

EDIT:
As pointed out by `Dan Dascalescu`, apparently it isn't using express anymore, it seems they have cloned the connect API but aren't using either.

Comment: Does iron-router [actually](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/search?q=express&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) use [express](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.send&type=Code)?

Comment: Interesting.  No apparently it doesn't anymore. No references in live code for connect either.