# Send base64 object to expressjs server

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, base64

I got base64 object from canvas

```
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

And I try to send this base64 object (imageData) to server via ajax:

```
var _data = {};
// set test property:
_data.avatar = imageData;
console.log(_data);
// Make an Ajax request
$.post('./setup', _data, function(result) {
console.log('result', result);
});
```

In my nodejs server (using only express midleware), I got a simple router to process this request

```
router.post('/setup', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('setup: data', req.body.data);
    console.log('setup: check', req.body.check);
    console.log('setup avatar: ', req.body.avatar);
    res.json({
    success:true
    });
});
```

Actually, it is not working and I wonder why the base64 object cannot be sent. 
In another cases my json object with text inside can send to server nomally..
Thank for your help and solution to send base64 object to expressjs server

Comment: What are the outputs of the console.logs?
Side note: Are you using `bodyParser`?

Comment: Yes...I am using bodyParse @Swaraj Giri...nothing in console log in my server

Comment: Check `req.body` and check what the ajax request is sending in the developer console. Are you serializing the data that you are sending via ajax?

Comment: noting inside the req.body...I was doing a test with serializing and non-serializing data but no case can pass my base64 obj to server. ???

Comment: Actually, the command like of console is not triggerd.. @Swaraj Giri..
Just only morgan output tell me that the post requets is comming on server...:(

Comment: Serialize your data, check if the xhr request is getting triggered, check the `XHR` tab in dev tools in browser.

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:50315
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/setup
Request Method:POST
Status Code:413 Request Entity Too Large

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to increase the limit of data your body parser can handle like:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: this is help me, so i know the problem in limitation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer on how to set the allowed body size:

- [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large)