# Nodejs with NGINX: When Sending large post data around 5 MB. The request is not reaching to post method in express?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am making a post request to the nodejs express post method. We are using NGINX with nodejs. When data is more than 25 records the request is not reaching to the post method in express. Earlier it was throwing "413 Request Entity Too Large" error. When changed `client_max_body_size` to 7M; it is not throwing any error.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Node JS - Express Request entity too large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: maybe body-parser issue ? you need to increase its max size aswell if you send large jsons.