# Request Entity Too Large

Tags: node.js, express

My Express application is returning "Request Entity Too Large" on a file upload of only a 125kb PNG file.

I have configured the body parser middleware as such:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '5mb',
  type:'*/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  extended: true
}));
```

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions). No matter how high I set the limit, or what combination of options, I always get the same result. I am using Express 4.13.3 and body-parser 1.15.2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many possible answers here, did you give them all a try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large

Comment: Hi @StéphaneBruckert Yes, I've done quite a bit of research. I've changed the order of the parsers, I've removed the json body parser and only used the urlecoded parser. I've tried adding the `parameterLimit` option... none of the answers that are working for others seems to be working for me.

Comment: Are you uploading the file as Base64 or something? Because `body-parser` doesn't handle (proper) file uploads at all.

Comment: @robertklep No, as a multi-part form using Postman, setting a `Content-Type` header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then setting a `form-data` body with a "photo" field and selecting a PNG file.

Comment: I've tried skipping the `body-parser` and using multer middleware, but I get the same response.

Comment: Multipart form data can't be uploaded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (it should use `multipart/form-data`), perhaps that's the problem. So dont' set the `Content-Type` and use `multer`. Also, I assume that you're not using any other middleware that could be causing that response.

Comment: @robertklep Well, this is embarrassing, but I had my route handler pointed to the wrong router (they are very close in name). Now I have a different error - the multer handler isn't picking up the file.

Comment: @Brandon not even with the correct content-type header?

Comment: It seems that Postman sends an array of files, even if you only send one, so `request.file` was `undefined`, but `request.files` was populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I had accidentally pointed my route handler to the wrong Express Router instance. Once I was pointed to the correct handler, Multer picked up the multi-part POST correctly.

Interestingly, when testing with Postman, it will send an array of files, even if you only select one, which is why `request.file` was `undefined`, but `request.files` contained the correct value.