# Azure App Service IIS "maxRequestLength" setting

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

I have a NodeJS application deployed on a Azure App Service.
Doing a post with a file of 38 MB I obtain a 404 error but under the hood there is a IIS problem `"Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value."`

To set '**maxAllowedContentLength**' I have to edit '**web.config**' file.

This is not good because if I do some change on the Azure Portal App Settings my local version of **web.config**' goes in conflict with the auto-generated file.

Is it possible to set on '**maxAllowedContentLength**' in a different way ?

Comment: What's the problem with adding maxAllowedContentLength as an App Setting in Azure Portal?

Comment: Exactly but as I know is not yet present as option in App Settings of Azure Portal

Comment: Editing auto-generated **web.config** is it possible to set the Threshold. Thanks to Fred

Answer (score 2):

> "Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value."

As far as I know, the default value of maxAllowedContentLength is 30000000 (approximately 28.6MB). We could [connecting to a Windows Azure Website from IIS Manager with remote administration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/), and then we could find the request limits, like this.

[image]

So the request will fail when you post about 38MB data. On my side, I increase the value of maxAllowedContentLength in web.config, I could post the data that is larger than 28.6MB from my Web API.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="<valueInBytes>"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Request to my Web API:

[image]

You could configure/modify maxAllowedContentLength property in your local web.config and deploy your app with web.config to your Azure Website. If you get any conflict error, please share us the error details.

Comment: If I create a web.config file containing only that setting the application stop to working ! Probably I make some error writing the file. Can you give me a valid example ? thanks !

Comment: My web.config is 
`<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
`
with this file any request goes in 404 !

Comment: Please try to view and edit the auto-generated web.config to configure requestLimits property of requestLimits uisng [kudu or App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).

Comment: @Toto do you fix the issue?

Comment: yes @Fred Han I did as you say starting from autogenerated file. thanks !

Comment: If it is helpful, please mark it as accepted answer to help other community members quickly find it and fix the similar issues.

Comment: Thank you!! this helped me so much. I deployed a web app using Node and Express onto Azure and I used multiple middleware such as multer, busboy, I was driving myself crazy debugging. Anyways there were no messages when I uploaded larger files it just failed and restarted in Azure. So I started testing file sizes and wow! I added this line to my config set the bytes to what I needed republish and I was laughing. Cheers.