# Node js - How to send request into small chunk of data (Error: request entity too large)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, request

Every time I am trying to send a huge Json object(contains images base64) over the network to my node js server.I get this

> Error: request entity too large

There is solution like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large) (***stackoverflow question***) that recommend to increase the limit on the node js server. I am looking for a client side solution. Is there any way to break down the data sent and have the server wait to receive all the packets and then process? (promise??)

*Hypothetically speaking*, if my files is 20mb, even if my limit is set to 5mb, I will be able to send it, it will just take more time. Is it possible? *Can you please put me on the right track?*

I am using express on the back end side

Here some code to refer:

```
    //AJAX CALL
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax('/module/report/ddl',{
        data: {
            widget: JSON.stringify(widget), <--- large, very large
            filename: filename,
            username: username,
            reportname: reportName
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
            //Do something
            promise.resolve(result);
        },
        error :function(err) {
            /* Act on the event */
            promise.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Here is my server side

```
   router.route('/ddl').post(ddlReport));
   function ddlReport(req, res){
     var filename = req.body.filename;
     var widgets = req.body.widget; <--- Once again large
     var username = req.body.username;


ctrl.ddlProcess(widgets,filename,title,username,function(err, result){
    if(err){
        res.status(422).send(err);
    }else {
        res.send(result);
    }
});
```

}

If you need anymore information, let me know! I am trying to find a solution that would be best even if it is not the one that I suggested!

Thank you for your time! Have good day!

Comment: 1) make a sync request to server so that file transfer is ensured. an async request would not stop user from going to a different url and killing your long upload
2) express need not do anything here. you can break the result of JSON.stringify by a length (say 5,000,000 bytes), name each chunk in serial sequence, add it up at server (you'd need to save these chunks in your session).
3) use a flag to know the last chunk of the file. like totalChunkCount or lastChunk=true

Comment: 1) So to do so I just add async: false to my ajax call, right? 2 & 3) I am new to express but I will check how to store my data into the user's session. And when it received the last chunk it execute the process, it makes sense thank you!

Comment: yes you should use sessions for this. check this https://github.com/expressjs/session. also have a backing store like redis or mongodb and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your help I have a 'temporary' working demo but I am using sync ajax call which is deprecated. I will try to publish an answer using promise soon

Comment: yes you can easily chain promises.. and they are async.. thats the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to break your large json into small pieces and send them separately? Just add some additional info like {packet: 1, total: 20, data: ... (one small piece of large data)}
Then send them at same time via ajax or one by one. And on node server side collect all of those 20 pieces.  Additionally you can have some checksum.

Comment: How do I make the server wait to receive all package? Is there a way to do that with express?

Comment: Create an object and add each asyncronusly received peace to that object. And receiving enery peace please perform check if all peaces are received