# Error: request entity too large IN NODE server

Tags: node.js, body-parser

i am trying to increase the file size limit in nodejs server. after searching and making changes also iam still getting same error. Tried everything mentioned on stackoverflow and also other sites but couldn't solve the issue. i have been wasting more time on this. please some one help me with this

**app.js :**

```
var express = require("express");

var Middlewares = require("./config/middlewares/middleware");


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  

var app = express();

var port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 5000;

app.set("port", port);

app.use(Middlewares.configuration);

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + port);
});

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "dinely.api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "dinely",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "method-override": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

**front-end**

**html :**

```
<div class="column">
                            <p class="label">Logo<span class="required">*</span></p>
                            <div >
                                <input type="file" name="logo" required (change)="fileChange(input)" #input style="text-indent: 0px;"/>
                                <img [attr.src]='file_srcs' alt="" style="width:15%;margin-top:10px;"/>
                                <div *ngIf="logoValid" class="help-block" style="color:red">Select Image</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**component.ts :**

```
  fileChange(input) {  
      debugger;
        this.readFiles(input.files);  

  }  

  readFiles(files) {  

      let reader = new FileReader();

      this.readFile(files[0], reader, (result) => {  

              var img = document.createElement("img");  
              img.src = result;  

              this.fileExtension = files[0].type.replace("image/","");

              this.resize(img, 250, 250, (resized_jpeg, before, after) => {  

                  this.debug_size_before.push(before);  
                  this.debug_size_after.push(after);  
                  console.log("before : " + this.debug_size_before + " after : " + this.debug_size_after)
                  this.file_srcs = resized_jpeg; 

                  var formdata =  new FormData();
                  formdata.append("formImg",resized_jpeg);

                  console.log(formdata);

              });  
          });  
  }

  // for image compression
  resize(img, MAX_WIDTH: number, MAX_HEIGHT: number, callback) {  

    return img.onload = () => {  

        var width = img.width;  
        var height = img.height;  

        if (width > height) {  
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {  
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;  
                width = MAX_WIDTH;  
            }  
        } else {  
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {  
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;  
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;  
            }  
        }  

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");  

        canvas.width = width;  
        canvas.height = height;  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);  

        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/' + this.fileExtension);  

        callback(dataUrl, img.src.length, dataUrl.length);  
    };  
  }

  readFile(file, reader, callback) {  

      reader.onload = () => {  
          callback(reader.result);  
          this.imageURL = reader.result;  
          this.uploadImgToServer(reader.result);
      }  

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  // upload image to server api call
  uploadImgToServer(url){

    return this._dataService.uploadImage({

              "imgUrl" : url,
              "path" : "/images/RestaurantLogos",
              "name" : this.generateRandomImgName(),
              "extension" : this.fileExtension 

            }).then(
              data => {           
                console.log("iamge uploaded");
              },
              error => {
              });
  } 

  // generates random string for image name
  generateRandomImgName(){

    var dt = new Date(); 
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";  

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)); 
    }  

    this.imagepath = text;

    return text;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: How large is the data that you're sending to the server? How are you sending it, exactly?

Comment: it was just 2mb file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in this link

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytes

**limit**

Controls the maximum request body size. If this is a number, then the value specifies the number of bytes; if it is a string, the value is passed to the bytes library for parsing. Defaults to '100kb'.

They mentioned limit values is in bytes

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

you have to set the limit in bytes.

Comment: the problem i was thinking would be that, from front-end i am sending the image by encrypting it to base64, but body parser will not work for file uploads. I don't know if i was correct or not.

Comment: @san2706 perhaps you should add your frontend code to your question

Comment: @robertklep i have added the front-end code as well, please take a look