# NodeBB error when upload file - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, body-parser, nodebb

I'm getting a visual error when trying to upload a file with 2.6MB. This says:

**Request Entity Too Large**.

[image]

Even with upload configurations enabled to 20MB.

[image]

I've read that this error is related to bodyParser limit, so i tried to solve this changing lines on **nodebb/src/webserver.js** lines **157** and **158**

From this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

to this (with no success)

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '20mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '20mb', type: 'application/json'}));
```

I've also searched in Nodebb repository, but there's no problem like that.
If someone could help me on that, i will be greatful.

Comment: Seems to be an Express related error and googling "nodejs Request Entity Too Large" brings ~50k results...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is behind nginx you need to set the limit in nginx as well. Add `client_max_body_size 5M;` into your nginx config.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help, i'll check if NodeBB is behind nginx, i give you some feedback when i test.

Comment: Several years later i'm back to thank you, this is the right solution. For more details, you need to put this property inside location / {} at nginx/sites-available/mysiteconf