# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I got the following error with bodyParser:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
at readStream (/root/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
at getRawBody (/root/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
at read (/root/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
at urlencodedParser (/root/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:116:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (/root/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:118:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at initialize (/root/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/root/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (/root/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:118:7)
```

the code is following

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

function setEntity(req, res) {
   // something....
}

module.exports = (app) => {

  const router = new express.Router();

  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

  router.use('/set/', (req, res) => {
    setEntity(req, res);
  });

  return router;
};
```

It seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

So I tried these 3 solutions.

1.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

2.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

3.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024*20, type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:1024*1024*20,type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoding' }));
```

but the result didn't change.

another setting is like below

```
nginx has this setting : client_max_body_size 200M;
data size is under 500kb (json).
express : 4.15.3
body-parser : 1.18.2
```

I have no idea why I can't change limit data size.

Comment: I found *app.use(bodyParser.json());* on another file. And I could solve this problem with this line. Thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

My issue was because I had

```
app.use(express.json())
```

and also

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))
```

and

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

I solved it after removing `app.use(express.json())`. Hope it helps somebody with the same issue.

Answer (score 21):

Controlling the maximum request body size will do the trick, however, you do not need *body-parser* anymore. Instead of using body-parser middleware, use the new Express implementation:

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));
```

You can find [here](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#express.urlencoded) the complete documentation.

Comment: I have moved away from `bodyParser`, but there are little holes like this that need filling. Thank you for helping fill the gaps!

Answer (score 5):

None of them works for me I couldn't change the limit by writing these

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

You can change the limit from **node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js**

```
? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb') to  ? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '50mb')
```