# NodeJS Router payload too large

Tags: node.js, rest, express, payload

I'm creating rest endpoints in my nodejs application as follows:

In my server.js I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(require('./routes/APIRoutes'));
```

I also tried the code below instead of using the express.json and expres.urlencoded as suggested on the potential duplicate question.

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(require('./routes/APIRoutes'));
```

In my APIRoutes file I have the following code:

```
/* --- INIT --- */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true });

router.post('...', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
...
});
```

I tried different combinations and orders for setting the limit higher. But currently every time I send a payload of 2kb, I get an 413 "(Payload Too Large)" error back.

Any help what the correct location is for setting the limit?

Comment: Are you using a proxy server on top

Comment: Nope, it's just on my localhost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: @TKJohn I tried the code from that issue using the app.use way, but it's not working for me. :(

Comment: @TKJohn Actually I found the solution in an unaccepted answer of that issue. THANKS!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem in one of the unaccepted answers of the suggested duplicate of TKJohn.
I had to add the parameter limit so that my code became:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

After the addition it worked!

I was also ablo to remove the code from APIRoutes.js

```
router.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
```

Comment: I tried using this, But no working for me. express version 4.17

Comment: How do you handle the error when the file size is bigger than that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this straightaway in `express` if you are using the latest version of `express`.

```
    let express = require('express');

    let app = express();

    app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

*Please note that this will only work with `express` versions bundled with `bodyParser`
(`bodyParser` was added back to `express` in release [4.16.0](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0))*

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
this.express.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb" ,extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

Comment: This looks the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024140/6243352) with a random `this.` added. Can you clarify what the difference is? If there is, none, I suggest upvoting the existing answer rather than posting it again.

Answer (score 1):

Tried looking online for past couple of hours and found no solution to 413 Payload

Turns out in **urlencoded.js** within the body-parser module there are additional options which take care of limits.

Options like **parameterLimit** and **arrayLimit** are items to amend if your parameter or array size exceeds the limit that is granted by default (which is 100 for array size).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I have tried all those suggestions or solutions but failed to work.

**Are you uploading file?**

In my case, I was using [multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) and also was uploading files with it.

The simple way to solve this is to not set a Content-Type.

my problem was that I was setting on my headers: `Content-Type: application/json` and I am [was] using multer:
so my app was trying to parse the uploaded audio file to JSON when the solution:

```
...
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
...
```

...is used and or the server complaints of large payload when it is removed.

Currently, my code is working

on my code, I have just this with the above solution that was failing base on my app case (file upload):

```
const express = require('express');

...

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
...
```

...And it is working because I removed Content-Type on my postman headers.

Make sure you are not using Content-Type on the headers when sending the request. If you care to know I was not setting it either on the express app(API).