# Entity Too large in Node js(Express.js version is 4.16.1)

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting 'Entity Too large' while post json in node js.
My expreess js version is 4.16.1.

I am gone through all answer from this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large`

Comment: did you use `app.use(bodyparser.json({limit: '2mb'}))` to override the default limit imposed by `body-parser` ?

Comment: default body-parser limit is `100kb`. See [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit-1) here.

Comment: I have already tried this code but it is not helping me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Answer (score 0):

After So many try I got my solution

I have commented this line

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and I put `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))`

Than it works

Comment: Answer is already there why you creating duplicate questions? @Maulik Patel https://stackoverflow.com/a/36514330/4652706

Comment: I have created new Question to specific Express Version.
In last Thread they were talking about express version below 4.0
and no one mentioned to comment app.use(bodyParser.json()); line

Comment: That is not enough to create questions, read the document again before create another question. @Maulik Patel.

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter as middle ware in your main js file

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: 1024102420}));
app.use( bodyParser.json({parameterLimit: 50000,limit:1024102420,type:'application/json'}) );     // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 50000, limit: 1024102420,    // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
  }));
```