# Nest.js - request entity too large PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to save a `JSON` into a Nest.js server but the server crash when I try to do it, and this is the issue that I'm seeing on the console.log:

`[Nest] 1976   - 2018-10-12 09:52:04   [ExceptionsHandler] request entity too large PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`

One thing is the size of the JSON request is 1095922 bytes, Does any one know How in Nest.js increase the size of a valid request? Thanks!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the solution, since this issue is related to express (Nest.js uses express behind scene) I found a solution in this thread [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large),
What I did was to modify the `main.ts` file add the `body-parser` dependency and add some new configuration to increase the size of the `JSON` request, then I use the `app` instance available in the file to apply those changes.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(`${__dirname}/public`);
  // the next two lines did the trick
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: if express verion is higer than 4.x.

the code is like ```app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb' }))```

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express-json-middleware

Answer (score 111):

you can also import `urlencoded` & `json` from express

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { urlencoded, json } from 'express';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: much better solution than adding extra library

Comment: @NenadJovicic actually the `body-parser` is already included and used by `express` and author of NestJS recommends using it: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/529#issuecomment-376576929
So it's most probably the same.

Answer (score 15):

The solution that solved for me was to increase bodyLimit. Source: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
AppModule,
new FastifyAdapter({ bodyLimit: 10048576 }),
```

Comment: This is the right solution for Nest Fastify Apps.

Comment: the link is dead and doesnt appear to work with the latest version of nest

Answer (score 4):

The default limit defined by body-parser is 100kb:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/0632e2f378d53579b6b2e4402258f4406e62ac6f/lib/types/json.js#L53-L55

Hope this helps :)

For me It helped and I set 100kb to 50mb

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT use body-parser directly, it will break some configs by nestjs

according to https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10471#issuecomment-1418091656

using `app.useBodyParser` to add body-parser middleware

Answer (score 2):

This resolved my issue and also in nestjs bodyparser is depreciated now so this might be an apt solution.

```js
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added it like this:

```
import { json as expressJson, urlencoded as expressUrlEncoded } from 'express';

// You init your app here: app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule

if (app !== undefined) { 
  app.use(expressJson({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(expressUrlEncoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its helps for me:

```js
app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the suggested answers of increasing the json and urlencoded limit. But the issue persisted because it was working on local but not on the server URL.

The issue was with the nginx server so I had to increase the limit too using the answer from [nestjs 413 payload too large MULTIPART](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75095803/14405473).

By adding to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

So check also the max accepted by the server your application is hosted on.