# How to set CORS for two applications running as docker

Tags: javascript, docker, express

I'm running my frontend application (nextJS) at https://editor.website.com and my backend application (expressJS) at https://api.editor.website.com - both as docker container.
I'm trying to upload some image files using graphQL and mostly it works, but sometimes it fails with these two errors:

```
POST https://api.editor.website.com/graphql 413

Access to fetch at 'https://api.editor.website.com/graphql' from origin 'https://editor.website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I tried to set universal cors to prevent this problem, but this doesn't work. So what am I missing?

**Server**

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.options('*', cors())
// app.use(cors())

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's `CORS` related if it works most of the time (you might receive `CORS` errors because you don't hit that middleware in the chain if another one terminates it). From what I can tell you receive `413 - Request Entity Too Large`.

I don't have much experience with Apollo server side but you should try the following according to [Apollo API Reference](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#apolloserverapplymiddleware):

```js
server.applyMiddleware({
    app, path: '/graphql',
    cors: {
        origin: 'https://editor.website.com',
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    },
    bodyParserConfig: {limit: '50mb'} // or your desired limit
})
```

**EDIT:**

We continued the discussion in chat and found out that there was an nginx reverse proxy in front of the service which had a limit of `1MB` request size. This solved the problem: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/981#issuecomment-345434827

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. Still the same problem. Only with some files (always the same), but locally everything works.

Comment: Are those files larger than the other ones which are working fine?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a valid issue, but this might be the cause: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3279

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, I found another issue here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464415/increasing-body-limit-size-in-apollo-server-express. Seems like a valid bug in Apollo server.

Comment: No, I don't see a difference between the files. They are all from the same type with nearly the same size and dimensions. So I don't see anything from where to start debugging.

Comment: It might not be `bodyparser` if they are the same size :/

Comment: They are all nearly 1MB. But as I see most of them hav 800-900kb, if the files are 1.2MB the upload is failing. So it seems to be a 1MB limit... But in this case your solution should have worked...

Comment: Ah I see, then I think it really is a `bodyparser` limit related issue. The solution I provided might not work because there is a bug in Apollo server (see the links I provided).

Comment: Seems like `bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'})` solved the problem for some people: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/288

Comment: Do you have some kind of reverse proxy in front of your service in production? (Where is it deployed to?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205001/discussion-between-user3142695-and-h3yduck).