# Error: StatusCodeError: 413 - {"error":{"code":413,"message":"request entity too large"}}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

We have this request error where we were not able to send the request in express server even though we set parameterLimit and bodyParser.

we have tried setting parameterLimit:50000000000000, but still the same issue

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '15360mb', type: 'application/json'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '15360mb', extended: true, type: 'application/json', parameterLimit: 5000000}))
```

We use

```
Node:8.9.4
body-parser: '1.18.3'
express: '4.17.0'
```

Comment: Can you try making extended false?

Comment: hi suyesh, its still the same status. I still get {"error":{"code":413,"message":"request entity too large"}}

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> request entity too large
>
> This error will occur when the request body's size is larger than the `"limit"` option. The limit property will be set to the byte limit and the length property will be set to the request body's length. The status property is set to 413 and the type property is set to 'entity.too.large'.
>
> limit
>
> Controls the maximum request body size. If this is a number, then the value specifies the number of bytes; if it is a string, the value is passed to the bytes library for parsing. Defaults to '100kb'

So you've to increase the `limit` option. For example, for `json`, setting `limit` to `10 MB`

```
bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' })
```

Comment: app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}) );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit:50000
})); this worked for us thanks