# Entity is too large in node js version(express": "^4.17.1",)

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I am trying to send 6 based64 images with some other data but I keep getting error `entity is too large` even I have added below code in my `app.js` file

```
 `app.use(bodyparser.json({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }))

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))`
```

If I try with the postman then there is no error only  with web application.

I am using Angular as Front-end.

I don't know why this error is occurring.

Kindly your help would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: may [help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: @user753642 I have gone through that solution as well but still same error.

Comment: Did you check the size of your upload limit to see if express is responding to your changes?

Comment: @MEDZ how can I check ?

Comment: As from the link shared above by @user753642 you can go to `node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:10` and add `console.log('Limit file size: '+limit);` and then restart and check your console logs.

Comment: Hi,I am not to see such file

Comment: Hi, Can you me where I can find this file because I am not able to this file

Comment: express server is not behind a ```proxy``` like ```Nginx```or something else?

Comment: Are you using ```multer```?

Comment: Yes I am using multer

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
var fs = require('fs');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, './public');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png');
        }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body.key1);
        fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
        });
})
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to submit images using this way but I have 6 images with  the specific name like `Aimg`, `Bimg` `Cimg` etc. so when return the path then how I will send the path of relevant image

Comment: because from return array how I will identify which image is of which  parms