# Getting error PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large in case of Using express.Router() Post call

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am trying to POST call using Router through express but I am getting request entity too large error, can anyone please help to solve the issue?

I want to set mb limit to my POST call payload. I have tried app.use() limit setting through body-parser but seems to get the same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default request size is **100kb** in body-parser. try this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb', extended: true}));
```

**make sure to add this before defining the routes**

Comment: thanks @Ajantha Bandara it is working for me after adding line number 1 before defining routes.

It will be better if you explained the both lines meaning or please provide the link where this details are provided.

Answer (score 2):

For total noobs like me be sure to either just use bodyParser.json or express.json
I had both of these in my code and so no amount of changing body parser helped because it was using express.json to handle requests.

```
app.use(express.json()); 

const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

there is a larger thread for this over on the other link.

[Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)