# verdaccio Error: 413 Payload Too Large - PUT request entity too large

Tags: node.js, express, npm, verdaccio

i was use  Verdaccio which is a lightweight private npm proxy registry built in Node.js

when i publish my code to verdaccio ,it always have a Error:

[image]

the logs file key word:
15 notice === Tarball Details ===
16 notice name:          canwin-viewer3d
16 notice version:       1.0.0
16 notice package size:  21.9 MB
16 notice unpacked size: 50.4 MB
16 notice shasum:        63d555be03e0c7a7b6dcdfb662d29c48b21d8c53
16 notice integrity:     sha512-KFz0gTPJusdfV[...]VIeII6rrcv4IA==
16 notice total files:   733
17 notice
18 http fetch PUT 413 http://localhost:4873/canwin-viewer3d 677ms
19 verbose stack Error: 413 Payload Too Large - PUT http://localhost:4873/canwin-viewer3d - request entity too large
19 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
19 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
20 verbose statusCode 413
21 verbose pkgid canwin-viewer3d@1.0.0
22 verbose cwd C:\work\viewer3d
23 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
24 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "publish"
25 verbose node v13.10.1
26 verbose npm  v6.13.7
27 error code E413

it seems that the PUT Quest PayLoad was Large ,so i try to find the verdaccio config file,but i have nothing ,verdaccio it code maybe use node express to run ,how can i setting  the Put Payload size?

Answer (score 7):

So generally you can face two problems with 413 errors.

- Verdaccio default body size is 1 MB so you have to increase that on the client side:

`npm config set max_body_size 100mb --registry https://<your registry>`

- If this does not work then you may need to increase it on the server side as the [doc](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/configuration.html#max-body-size) suggest. Add to the configuration file the following line.

values.yaml

```
...

  max_body_size: 100mb

....
```

- If this still does not work then most likely you have a problem with your proxy.

If this is a `nginx` proxy you can try:

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

or if this is a `node.js` server you can use the `bodyParser` as described in detail in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: can you tell me please how can I increase max_body in the server side? I don't have this file on my machine values.yaml, nginx.conf

Comment: Can you maybe explain how did you install verdaccio?

well, in the case if you are using kubernetes, I recommend deploying verdaccio via its [helm repository](https://github.com/verdaccio/charts/tree/master/charts/verdaccio).
Then you can set the value `max_body_size` in the [values.yaml](https://github.com/verdaccio/charts/blob/master/charts/verdaccio/values.yaml) file.

You only need the `nginx` proxy if you are routing your traffic via an `nginx` server.(base d on your comment you do not)

Comment: Hello! But if I did not installed Verdaccio. For publish npm package you did not need to install it. But what to do if this command <npm config set max_body_size 100mb> is not working? And I did not install any proxy for Verdaccio, it does not need too for publish package.

Comment: Well, you could add this to your npmrc config file. Usually it is located in `${HOME}/.npmrc`:
`max_body_size: 200mb=true`

Have you tried that?

Other than that if you don't use Verdaccio, but the official NPM website, you can look around your repo seetings there. What seems to be your issue?

Comment: I tried to change .npmrc file, but it is not working.  Get the error after npm publish: 413 Request Entity Too Large. My package about 163mb

Comment: Are you trying to publish to npmjs or privately hosted repo?

Comment: Its a private repo in Verdaccio

Comment: Setting max_body_size via `npm config` didn't fix the issue for me, but setting max_body_size in Verdaccio's config did, as per the docs: https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration/#max-body-size.

Comment: I just increased the limit on my Verdaccio server (running in a Docker container on my Synology NAS) by adding `max_body_size: 100mb` to the `config.yaml` file. I'm not aware of any `values.yaml` file, but changing the `config.yaml` does work. Also, I used `100mb` instead of `100M`, since that's the format the Verdaccio docs use. https://verdaccio.org/docs/configuration/#max-body-size