# PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large httpclientModule

Tags: angular, post, httpclient

in angular app (15.2.9), I need to upload to the srver large files;
this is how I make the request:

```
uploadAsset(token:string,asset){
console.log("uploading asset")
const url = "https://dev.thinkingadditive.com/v0/assets"
const options = {
headers:this.headersFactory(token),
observe:'body' as const,
withCredentials:true
}
  return this.http.post(url,asset,options)
}
```

I get this error:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

I have seen many posts with the same error with nodejs/express, I should change the payload limit, but I could not find how to change in angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)