# How to resolve HTTP error 431 - Nextjs + Next-Auth?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am receiving a photo in jwt via token that is not rendering

Tools used: nextjs, typescript, next-auth, keycloak, LDAP

The image comes from LDAP and goes to the keycloak user and my application is responsible for storing the jwt token after authentication, but when a user who has a photo the application gives error 431.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQXr.png)

code next-auth:

```
import { get, maxHeaderSize } from "http";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";
import { setGlobal } from "next/dist/trace";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.KC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.KC_ISSUER,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    // Servidor
    jwt: async ({ token, user, profile }) => {
      const customUser = profile as unknown as any

      console.log(setGlobal(maxHeaderSize, 1000))
      if (user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          newemail: customUser.mailPrimaryAddress,
          company: customUser.company,
          group: customUser.group,
          jpegPhoto: customUser.jpegPhoto
        }
      }
      return token
    },
    // Cliente
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      return {

        ...session,
        user: {
          // ...token
          // newemail: token.newemail
          name: token.name,
          email: token.email,
          // // PROPS CRIADAS
          // company: token.company,
          // group: token.group,
          // jpegPhoto: token.jpegPhoto,
        }
      }
    },
  },
  events: {
    async signOut() {
      await get(ENV)
    }
  }
}
```

code middleware

```
import { NextAuthMiddlewareOptions, NextRequestWithAuth, withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

const middleware = (request:NextRequestWithAuth) =>{
  console.log("[MIDDLEWARE_NEXTAUTH_TOKEN]: ", request.nextauth.token)

  const isPrivateRoutes = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/private/admin")
  const isAdminUser = request.nextauth.token?.group === 'admin'

  if(isPrivateRoutes && !isAdminUser){
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/denied', request.url))
  }
}
const callbackOptions:NextAuthMiddlewareOptions = {}

export default withAuth(middleware,callbackOptions)
export const config ={
  matcher: ['/private/:path*']
};
```

Thank you for your help in advance!!! I'm accepting tips and suggestions!

**EDIT**

component I'm trying to render the image

```
'use client'
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import Image from "next/image"

const ClientImage = () => {
  const session = useSession()

  const imgUrl = session.data?.user["jpegPhoto"]
  return (
    <div>
      {/* {session && <Image src={imgUrl} alt="imagem do usuario" />} */}
      {session && <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 1)}</pre>}
    </div>
  )
}

export { ClientImage }
```

Comment: The HTTP 431 code indicates that the server refuses to process the request because the request's HTTP headers are too long. You are storing a photo in a JWT token which is probably the root of the error. How long is the data in `customUser.jpegPhoto`?

Comment: The image is more or less 50mb. And how could I solve these problems?

I edited the question adding how I'm trying to add the image

Comment: I take back what I said earlier. From your code, it seems that `customUser.jpegPhoto` has a string data type which is a URL to the image, not the actual image itself as I had previously imagined. The issue is therefore not caused by the photo. The line             ` console.log(setGlobal(maxHeaderSize, 1000))` seems suspicious. Can you remove it and test your application again?

Comment: I added it precisely to try to resolve this. But I removed it and tested it again, and it still has the same error 431

Comment: You are not supposed to store additional information in a JWT because it has a limited size (approx 7KB). What you should do instead is create an API endpoint where the client can fetch his details in JSON format after logging in

Comment: but the credentials are coming from a keycloak api that is linked to an LDAP. There's no way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large/74664419#74664419

Comment: I'm not using express, I'm just using nextjs with typescript and next-auth, I'm authenticating with a user with a profile photo in LDAP but the jwt I receive is very large and it's giving me an error 431

Answer (score 1):

The solution that resolved the error was:

- Add to package.json in the dev part (for local) and start (in production)

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=12800000' next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=12800000' next start",
  },
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).