# Prevent large requests in NodeJS with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to prevent any (or particular) requests larger than set size.

**Example**: 1GB POST request. Limit - 5MB. The upload starts and once it hits 5MB, the server immediately flushes the memory, withdraws the request and sends an error back.

Is there any good mechanism to do it?

**Edit:** I use multipart requests.

**Duplicate**: [How to limit upload file size in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit upload file size in express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js)

Comment: Do you find some solution to multipart requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use body parser:

```
var bParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb'}));
```

doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#limit

Comment: Just edited my question. This parser says "This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature."

Comment: Is there any simple way to do without heavy modules such as busboy?

Comment: Can't you check then the  request.headers.content-length value in your onRequest event?

Comment: Is this secure? Can't malicious users just type whatever they want in content.length or send the data in chunks?

Comment: No it's not secure at all, you will need to check the actual body byte size eventually.

Comment: Exactly, how can I do it during the upload then? :)

Comment: expressjs is an open source, take a look at their GitHub repository: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/7847af6e5a36129eea0e0becfbcc521b839313ae/lib/types/json.js

Comment: What exactly are you doing after the request with the body data?

Comment: Does that actually matter in this case? Let's say I do nothing, just send an empty JSON back.

Comment: Well, it really can matter what are your doing, for instance if you are opening a stream with a client and read the data by chunks, you can stop the process as you reach the limit -  I am not really telling you to do so, I'm just saying that custom modifications usually relies on specific implementation.