# Using TOAST UI editor, I cannot upload image that has a over 50kb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, toast, toast-ui-editor

I have a problem that I had could not upload to my web-site to image file.

I have several image file. The thing I had succeded upload to image is 30kb~ 50kb.

But, the thing I had failed upload to image is over 50kb~.

I have used TOAST UI Editor, next js, express

Also, I detached to picture shown this problem.

[image]

left side, the rendering component. (5657~~  << It is just title. I want to image at 'content div'

right side, chrome developer mode in console.

I had non-error response. But, just there are no rendering.

below, rendering component.

```
const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log('저기', toJS(dynamicPost.post?.content))

  useEffect(() => {
    dynamicPost.postR(router.query.id);
  }, [router.query.id]);

  return useObserver(() => (
    <AppLayout>
      <div> {toJS(dynamicPost.post?.createdAt)} </div>
      <div> {toJS(dynamicPost.post?.title)} </div>
      <div> {ReactHtmlParser(toJS(dynamicPost.post?.content))} </div>

    </AppLayout>
  ));
};
```

Comment: you have successfully completed uploading under 50kb size image but failed over 50k. this is not a problem of TOAST UI or frontend issue but express's upload size limt issue. please check the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js

Comment: umm....I have tried to your direction. But, I cannot solved it. My terminal had shown me a error message - 'requrest aborted'. After I have saw this, i did to google for solve this error message. Not yet, I did not solved it....