# How to set upload file size in Expo to fix 'Payload Too Large'

Tags: javascript, node.js, expo

I still struggle to find the best solution for **uploading** a profile **image** and **connecting** the image with the **user** in the **database** in Expo. This is a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636237/use-expo-image-picker-package-to-create-image-file-and-database-entry-on-success).

[image]

I develop with Expo and having a `Profile` screen (see image). There I have an `Pick Image` button, some fields for the usernames and a `Submit button` for saving everything.

The image upload works and is done with:

```
let image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  allowsEditing: true,
  base64: true,
})
```

That means it is not transferred but available as Base64 in the variable.

So far so good. Now I have trouble in sending the image to the server. I found these options to solve it:

1. Doing it with an extra [**Express server**](https://medium.com/teaching-tech/react-native-take-images-and-upload-it-to-a-node-js-server-ca2d769cf657). But I don't like the approach overall. That would mean to have an additional server running. Also, when sending the image I cannot see how to safely connect the image with the user in the database.
2. The other idea was having [2 mutations](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/120) combined. I did it with this code:

   ```
   const UPDATEUSER_MUTATION = gql`
     mutation UpdateUserMutation($email: String!, $firstname: String!, $lastname: String!, $image: Upload!) {
       updateuser(email: $email, firstname: $firstname, lastname: $lastname) {
         firstname,
         lastname
       },
       uploadFile(file: $image)
     }
   `
   ```

So first send the regular mutation, that inserts the user fields. And after that another mutation is handling only the `image` itself. That worked but it gave me that error:

> HTTP/1.1 413 Payload Too Large

[image]

I mean that's correct. The usual upload size is 100 kB and the image is above. But as I do not use an express server, I'm not quite sure how to set that limit in my Expo project. [For an express server that would be easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js).

So the question is now, is the second approch good? Or should I go even another way. What is the best practice here?

And maybe the direction question: **How to set upload file size in Expo to fix 'Payload Too Large'?**