# XMLHttpRequest and fetch Limiting file upload size to 100mb

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

So I'm working on a simple project, it's a basic file upload system. Everything is working and running fine when I test the project locally, but whenever I run this program on my server, the file upload stops working at 100mb. It isn't speed, because at 99mb it uploaded in about 20 seconds. I only get 1 progress update when logging with the following function:

```js
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
                const progress = Math.floor(e.loaded/e.total*100)
                progressBar.style.width = progress + "%"
                progressBar.innerHTML = progress+"%"
                console.log(e.loaded/e.total*100)
            }, false)
```

When with a 99mb file, I get them almost every second. Again, all of this works fine on localhost with no issues, it is just on my server. I am wondering if there is some sort of client or server issue preventing this? I want to allow larger files. Thanks!

client code:

```html
<form id="uploadForm">
    <div class="card" style="width: 50vw;">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <button id="upload" disabled class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="progress" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">0%</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
    const uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload")
    const progressBar = document.getElementById("progress")

    uploadButton.onclick = () => {
        uploadFile(fileInput.files[0])
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {
        console.log(file)
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        if (xhr.upload) {
            const formdata = new FormData()
            uploadButton.disabled = true
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
                const progress = Math.floor(e.loaded/e.total*100)
                progressBar.style.width = progress + "%"
                progressBar.innerHTML = progress+"%"
                console.log(e.loaded/e.total*100)
            }, false)
            xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
                    window.location.pathname = response.path
                }
            }
            formdata.append("file", file)
            xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FILENAME", file.name)
            xhr.send(formdata)
        }
    }
    
    fileInput.onchange = event => {
        uploadButton.disabled = fileInput.value ? false : true
    }
</script>
```

server code:
using express and express-fileupload on npm
removed a lot of the unneeded stuff

```js
import express from "express"
import fileUpload, { UploadedFile } from "express-fileupload"

const app = express()
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: {
        files: 1
    }
}))
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
    const file = req.files.file as UploadedFile
    const key = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString("hex")
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join("./uploads", key))
    file.mv(path.join("./uploads", key, file.name))
    res.json({
        file: file.name,
        path: `/uploads/${key}/${file.name}`
    })
})
```

Comment: You need to configure your server to accept file uploads grater than 100mb. With loaclhost its common that you dont need to explicitly specify but on dev/prod server this is necessay. Here is a link to the stackoverflow question that answers your actual problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js

Comment: This didn't really work, I think my issue is more client side than server side, I just included server code in case it was necessary. If you go to https://files.tkdkid1000.net and upload something above 99mb you will see only one progress message in the javascript console. 99mb and lower and everything works just fine, with consistent(ish) upload progress messages.

Comment: I just managed to send a 270mb file on your server (the link you provided in your comment).

Comment: and on 100% completion I am getting an error code 413 - Request Entity Too Large from cloudfare, I suppose thats the server where you have hosted your application.

Comment: I presume this stackoveflow question's answer addresses your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large
Then again, its **not** frontend related!